# iPhone SDK releasing NSString

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory-management, nsstring

I'm new to Objective C and I have a simple question about memory management.

This is a simple method for a Button which changes a `UILabel` with the text in a `UITextField`.

```
-(IBAction) setLabel
{
    NSString *inputText = [[NSString alloc]initWithString:myTextField.text];

    [myLabel setText:inputText];
    [inputText release];
}
```

This code works fine. But If I change this code to following,

```
-(IBAction) setLabel
{
    NSString *inputText = [[NSString alloc]initWithString:@"some string value"];
    inputText = myTextField.text;       
    [myLabel setText:inputText];
    [inputText release];
}
```

Then application crashes on runtime. I have to remove the line `[inputText release];` to run application without crashing.
As far as I know if I created something with 'alloc' I have to release it. But here, if I release that string app crashes.Could someone please explain the reason?

Thanks in advance

Comment: In general, any time you're using `[[NSString alloc]initWithString:` (or the ever-popular `[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",someString]`) it's a bug.  There are places where `initWithString` is merited, but if you don't understand why your second example fails then you don't understand things well enough to use it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason that the release is crashing is because you're reassigning `inputText` to `myTextField.text`. The call to `release` is now releasing that string instead of the one allocated on the first line of `setLabel`. If you use another variable for that assignment, it should fix the crash.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer :] 
and in the 2nd code snippet , when I call 'release' it is trying to release the string in myTextField.text correct? and then What will happen to the life cycle of the 1st string @"some string value" ?

Comment: @user683803 Correct, you are releasing myTextField.text. Something else is calling release on it later, and that is causing the crash. Since the first string is never released, it will end up being a memory leak.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is not a direct answer to your question but you should try to use the autorelease pool to not have to worry about these details. Thus, if you had written your code as follows:

```
-(IBAction) setLabel
{
    NSString *inputText = [NSString stringWithString:myTextField.text];    
    [myLabel setText:inputText];
}
```

the code is more readable and, moreover, you are not responsible for releasing the `inputText` string instance.